# How to insert an image tag into XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I am using the following php code to create an XML file:

```
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>mytitle</title>
<description>my description</description>
<link>www.mysite.com</link>';

$sql = "SELECT title, description, url, picture, formatted_date 
FROM somewhere" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    //timestamp date to xml format
     $pubdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s O', strtotime($result_array[formatted_date]));

         echo '  
       <item>  
          <title>'.$result_array[title].'</title>
          <description>'.$result_array[description].'</description> 
          <link>'.$result_array[indit_url].'</link>  
          <pubDate>'.$pubdate.' GMT</pubDate> 

          <enclosure url="'.$result_array[picture].'" length="1121990" type="image"/>
            <image>
              <url>'.$result_array[picture].'</url> 
               <title>image title</title>   
               <link>'.$result_array[picture].'</link>         
                 <width>111</width>                             
               <height>33</height>                             
               <description>An amazing picture</description>   
   </image>      </item>';
```

The file created is correctly validated using http://validator.w3.org/, but when i try to use some xml parser like: http://simplepie.org/ the perser are not able to capture the images. Am i using a correct tag to insert image into xml file? Is there any other tags or method to inser images?

Comment: xml couldn't care less if you're inserting an image or text or whatever. it's just a markup language. it does not have "images".

Comment: What Mark B said.  Maybe you want to look at [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try escaping the special characters in the image tag.

Use `htmlspecialchars` on `$result_array[picture]`

**Also, can you show a sample of your rss feed here so that the answer can be more accurate.**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest surrounding the data in an XML escape structure -as such:

```
<image>
    <url><![CDATA[ imagedatagoeshere ]]></content></url>
</image>
```

However, I'm not familiar with simplepie, so I don't know if that understands CDATA properly.